# Full text indexing not working + Mysql 5.6.4

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE `table_copy` (
  `link_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fulltxt` mediumtext,
  `indexdate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `size` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `visible` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `level` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `state` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`link_id`),
  KEY `indexdate` (`indexdate`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `fulltext2` (`fulltxt`)
) ENGINE=INNODB AUTO_INCREMENT=274212 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

The above table contains about 2,74,211 records, when i tried to get data from table it takes 2 minutes to execute.

Query:   `SELECT c.link_id from table_copy c where MATCH(fulltxt) AGAINST('Council')`

How can i optimize  the above query?

Comment: Hi, welcome to dba.se! Unfortunately, we need more information to be able to help you. What exactly is not working?

Comment: Hello Derek, when i try to execute fulltxt indexed query using MATCH(...) AGAINST(...) it takes too much time to execute. how can i optimize the query to take minimum time to execute. For e.g. Less than a minute.

Comment: You need check - configuration of server, memory for InnoDB, for FullText

compare size of index and FT buffer size, by default it only 8Mb, max value is 80Mb

Than next step and profile query - how many records returned, what time of intialyze of index

Comment: Use [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html) to check the query plan and if it is using the index at all. Add the plan to your question too.

Answer (score 0):

You need check - configuration of server, memory for InnoDB, for FullText

compare size of index and FT buffer size, by default it only 8Mb, max value is 80Mb

Than next step and profile query - how many records returned, what time of intialyze of index

and upgrade 5.6.4 to something more new
in 5.6.4 FullText was only implement for InnoDB, many  bugs fixed from that time

Comment: Hello a_vlad, Thank u for replying. Currently my MySQL version is 5.6.23.

Comment: Hi Kunal! it better (in header 5.6.4), could You as well attach my.cnf (my.ini) and result of profile/explain query? You can do it manual - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/show-profile.html or I prefer use tools like - http://www.profilesql.com, and current server memory/processes state (top command)

Comment: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb%';`